# python text files

Tags: python

I have a text file which has been made from a excel file, in the excel file cell A2 has the name 'Supplier A'. When I import the text file and i use the following code:

```
filea = open ( "jag.txt").readlines()
lines =[x.split() for x in filea]
print lines [0][1]
```

It returns just 'supplier' and not Supplier A, the A is located in lines [0][2]. How dow I import it and have it recognise the complete word. Because if a copy the text field back into excel it does copy it properly so the txt file definitley recognises them as being together.

Comment: could you show a small portion of the text file as i think that would help answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel regulary is using the 'tab' as separtor sign for saving in 'txt' format.

So you should try something like this:

```
lines = []
with open('jag.txt') as f:
    lines = [ line.split('\t') for line in f.read().splitlines() ]
print(lines)
```

and should get something like this

```
[ ['A1', 'A2', ...], ['B1', 'B2'], ... ]
```

Why not only "f.readlines()"? Because using this, your last cell will also contain the *carriage return* sign ('\n').

Why using the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)? ***With*** will close the file finally, and this is a good election in any case.

An alternative way to *parse* your text file could be the python (included) **csv** module. Using the [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) can be a very convenient way to parse character separated files/structures:

```
with open('jag.txt') as f: 
    lines = [ line for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t') ]
```

-Colin-

Answer (score 3):

It does so because `str.split()` splits between every whitespace, tab and line break. You can use `str.split(',')` as an alternative, but in fact you really want to use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)-module for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

What character (space, tab, comma etc) are the values seperated on each line?  Your current code will split the text at whitespace, by using `split()` without a split character.